# How to compare similiar products and highlight differences and USPs?

Tags: comparison, component, highlight, product

As a user I want to compare different product variants and evaluate the one matching best my needs.

Most websites using comparison tables to show at a glance every single differenct feature.

For me this approach is massivly overloaded. If you'll search for a hair dryer and won't have any preferences, you whould always purchase the cheapest one. So to motivate the user I'd like to show him the advantages of a better and more expensive product. So in my eyes the user should get informed well why any other variant is more expensive and highlight the USPs at a glance.

Does anyone has a good example or an idea how a module like this should look like? The difficulty is to present all information inside one viewport without scrolling.

I'll be glad about every idea, recommendation and example.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is quite a tricky topic. The first step would be to determine your goal and user group. 
As far as I get your idea it's more a product comparison website.

1) To compare things you need a quality metric - or more than one. Price, durability, design, efficiency whatever. Basically these are the "rows" in a tabular comparison.

2) You have to display the products. Typically you'll have more than 5 choices. But you don't want to have a tabular comparison. Find a better way! (this is what you asked for I think...)

Suggestions:
A) Similar to pricing tables of companies/startups. something like this: Example: https://blog.kissmetrics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/kissmetrics-pricing.png
This is the typical display. Usually one is highlighted and recommended and the prices/features are stacked - so less people will buy the cheap one.

B) Videogame Carshop: those typical showrooms/carousel where you can see the difference between to cars via the barchart - aka performance metrics - see 1)
Example 1: http://www.carlosvk.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Rivals_004.jpg
Example 2: https://lh5.ggpht.com/NmUdxqbacLozAueds1NsBcQ_ShuzFY1gn2S6wiyS46pSJsl2qXgwdpPZJIguBD5uKZWX=h900

C) Use only key metrics - see 1) and use the typical market position chart:
Example: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Y597OhoXzXU/T55JqiCyzqI/AAAAAAAABkE/WTovUhZlL9k/s1600/Clipboard01.jpg
for advanced Users you could use more complex ones (spidercharts):
Example: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Spider_Chart2.jpg

just a few thoughts!

Comment: I will upload my sketches and research in a few days/weeks regarding your answers.